# How to add a search Icon as section for SearchBar in UITableView using search controller

Tags: ios, nsarray, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am trying to add the image for search (magnifying glass) as the section, to easily go to the search bar.

This is the issue I am experiencing:
[image]

My code to setup the sections is as follows:

Note: self.fbFriends is an Array of Dictionaries that include the facebook friends of the user.

```
self.fbFriends = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[[MESCache sharedCache] facebookFriends]];
self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

BOOL found;

[self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:UITableViewIndexSearch];

// Loop through the friends and create our keys
for (NSDictionary *friend in self.fbFriends)
{
    NSString *c = [[friend objectForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1];

    found = NO;

    for (NSString *str in [self.sections allKeys])
    {
        if ([str isEqualToString:c])
        {
            found = YES;
        }
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        [self.sections setValue:[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] forKey:c];
    }
}

// Loop again and sort the friends into their respective keys
for (NSDictionary *friend in self.fbFriends)
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:[[friend objectForKey:@"name"] substringToIndex:1]] addObject:friend];
}

// Sort each section array
for (NSString *key in [self.sections allKeys])
{
    [[self.sections objectForKey:key] sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES]]];
}
```

Here is my section setup and header views:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return [[self.sections allKeys] count];
    }
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return NSLocalizedString(@"FbFriendsSearchControllerSection", @"Fb Friends search controller - section title for search results table view");
    } else {
        return [[[self.sections allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:section];
    }
}
```

Does anyone see how this is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard practice. There is no need for the extra section just to show a search.

Don't add the "search" section to your `self.sections` dictionary. Instead, you just have sections for the actual data. Then in your `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:` method you can do:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    NSInteger res = 0;
    if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        if (index == 0) {
            // If the user taps the search icon, scroll the table view to the top
            res = -1;
            [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
        } else {
            res = ... // return the proper index for your data
        }
    } else {
        res = 0;
    }

    return res;
}
```

Side note - you really want to have an array of dictionaries. The main array should represent the sections. As you have it now, you are constantly getting your main dictionary's keys and sorting them. This will be done MANY times - all needlessly. Using an array lets you quickly get the data from the section index.

Comment: The facebook friend information is stored in an Array, each friend is a dictionary within the array. The dictionary for a friend then includes the id and name of the friend. I then loop through the array of dictionaries (self.fbFriends) collecting the first letter of each name to make an array for sections. How else would you recommend trying to complete this?

Comment: the self.sections is an array of string chars from the first char from each dictionary name (i.e. friend name), this is only created in viewDidLoad and not changed later, so it should be only created once?

Comment: No, `self.sections` is an `NSDictionary`, not an `NSArray`. How else could you be calling `allKeys` on it? You want an array created once so you don't have to call `allKeys` and sort the resulting array over and over and over like you are in the posted code.

Comment: Can you explain how this is being called over and over when it is run once in view did load only? Could you provide a code example of how to accomplish the same with an array please?

Comment: He is suggesting pulling out the `[self.sections allKeys]` into the view did load.